# Hover link does not display background fully

Tags: css, hyperlink, background, hover

When I hover the hover background which changes color only fits around the link and not the full background. Tried everything and cannot get it to work, can anyone help pls

```css
nav ul {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3333FF;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  transition: max-height 0.4s;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

a:visited {
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #0000EE;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
    <li><a href="# ">Contacts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Policies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Volunteer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Useful links</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `a` elements to `display: inline-block;` and move the padding from the `li` to the `a`:

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

Example:

```css
nav ul {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3333FF;
  transition: max-height 0.4s;
}

nav ul li, a {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  padding: 16px;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

a:visited {
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #0000EE;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
    <li><a href="# ">Contacts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Policies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Volunteer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Useful links</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change hover effect to li tag instead of a tag

```css
nav ul {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3333FF;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  transition: max-height 0.4s;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #0000EE;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

a:visited {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
    <li><a href="# ">Contacts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Policies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Volunteer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Useful links</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```